# Supported function within $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $\phi_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $|\phi_n(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Also suppose that $\text{supp } \phi_n \subset [a,b]$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a > b$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If in addition $\phi_n \to 0$ a.e., show that $\int \phi_n \to 0$.

I am asked to show this without using the Bounded Convergence Theorem. Here is what I have:

\begin{align}
\int |\phi_n(x)-0| &\le \int |\phi_n (x)| \\
&\le \int_{[a,b]} 1 \\
&= 1 \cdot m([a,b]) \\
&=b-a.
\end{align}
But I was hoping that $\int |\phi_n(x)-0| < \epsilon$ somehow.

I am stuck because I can't seem to make use of the fact that $\phi_n \to 0$ anywhere in my proof. I know I need to though. Should I use Egoroff's Theorem for this?

Comment: Congrats on $6 \sum_{i=0}^3 10^i$!

Comment: @Vandermonde Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Egoroff theorem states that for any $\varepsilon>0
 $ there is a set $A\subset\left[a,b\right]
 $ such taht $\left(\phi_{n}\right)_{n}
 $ converges uniformly on $\left[a,b\right]\setminus A
 $ and the measure of $A
 $ is less than $\varepsilon
 $. Since $\left(\phi_{n}\right)_{n}
 $ converges to $0
 $, there is an integer $n\in\mathbb{N}
 $ such that $\left\Vert \phi_{n}\right\Vert _{\infty}<\varepsilon
 $ on $\left[a,b\right]\setminus A
 $. Thus we have$$\left|\intop_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{n}\left(x\right)dx\right|=\left|\intop_{\left[a,b\right]}\phi_{n}\left(x\right)dx\right|\leq\left|\intop_{\left[a,b\right]\setminus A}\phi_{n}\left(x\right)dx\right|+\left|\intop_{A}\phi_{n}\left(x\right)dx\right|\leq\intop_{\left[a,b\right]\setminus A}\left|\phi_{n}\left(x\right)\right|dx+\intop_{A}\left|\phi_{n}\left(x\right)\right|dx\leq\intop_{\left[a,b\right]\setminus A}\left\Vert \phi_{n}\right\Vert _{\infty}dx+\intop_{A}1dx<\varepsilon\left(\left(b-a-\varepsilon\right)+1\right)
 $$ for any $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we may assume $[a,b]=[0,1].$

**Lemma**: Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ measurable, such that $f<1$ everywhere, and $\int_0^1f>\epsilon$. Then there is a subset $A\subset[0,1]$ of measure $\geq\epsilon/2$ on which we have $f\geq\epsilon/2$.

The lemma is not too hard to prove.

Assume the claim does not hold, so there is some $\epsilon>0$ and infinitely many functions in the sequence which satisfy $\int_0^1\phi_n>\epsilon$. By the lemma, it follows that the sequence does not converge to $0$ in probability. This is a contradiction since convergence almost everywhere is stronger than convergence in probability.